# Example of Google page ranking algorithm?

Tags: math, html, mathematical-optimization

I read Google page ranking algorithm from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank
[image: Google Page Ranking simple algorithms].

My question is why only outbound links are used in page rank calculation? Is inbound link don't affect the page rank by any mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation turn outbound links to page A into a score.

Another way to phrase it is The equation scores page A `inbound links`

So actually inbound links are all that matter.